# Suspicious open ports on my Ubuntu server

Tags: security, port

I recently did a port scan (using [www.ipfingerprints.com](https://www.ipfingerprints.com)) on my Ubuntu 18.04 server and found a number of ports that I did not open. Here are the open ports:

```
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp  open     ssh
25/tcp  open     smtp
80/tcp  open     http
111/tcp filtered rpcbind
135/tcp filtered msrpc
136/tcp filtered profile
137/tcp filtered netbios-ns
138/tcp filtered netbios-dgm
139/tcp filtered netbios-ssn
443/tcp open     https
445/tcp filtered microsoft-ds
513/tcp filtered login
520/tcp filtered efs
```

Except for 22, 25, 80 and 443, I did not open the rest of these ports. Why are they open, and will it affect my server performance if I close all of these ports?

Comment: `filtered` means they are blocked by a firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute `ss -tunapl` to see which programs open the ports. Disable the services that are not needed, using `systemctl disable <service-name>.service.`

The above list looks like samba and related services are running.

Comment: I'd rather say the hoster has blocked these ports. They don't have to be running.

Comment: `ss -tunapl` gives a very good breakdown of what ports are open. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Those ports are not open. Filtered means they are blocked by a firewall, and that doesn't mean that without this firewall the port would be open. They are probably just closed.

Verify with `netstsat -tanp|grep LISTEN`

Comment: Except you want to use `ss` instead of `netstat`, which has been obsolete for years and is not typically installed by default on modern Linux systems.

Answer (score 1):

nmap indicating "filtered" simply means that the packets are being blackholed somewhere between your nmap 
client and the target being scanned.
Filtered means that a firewall, filter, or other network obstacle is blocking the port so that Nmap cannot tell 
whether it is open or closed.-- http://nmap.org/book/man.html
Ref: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14706/found-unusual-services-running-on-my-vps